# HTML/CSS - How to display background image (icon) with some clearance to the right of the icon?

Tags: html, css

The following css is for styling an input textbox with a icon on invalid inputs.

How can I get the icon to appear with some padding/margin immediately to the right of the icon when the icon appears?

Right now, the icon is touching the right boundary of my text input.

What modifications do I need to do to make this work?

```
.error{
  outline: solid 1px red !important;
  background: url('./resources/icons/icon_warning@2x.png') no-repeat scroll right !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  order-right: 10px solid transparent !important;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eeeeee !important;
  background-size: 15px 15px !important;
  padding-left: 20px !important;
  padding-right: 18px !important;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example so we can debug?

Comment: Yes, working on it now.

Comment: Why are you using `!important`? It's generally not a good idea, and can be solved by making the selector more specific.

Comment: Please see fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/d3qkLgh2/1/

Comment: First of all, it's not really the simplest way to do this, but it looks like you added a 10px transparent border as a workaround in your fiddle -- the reason this isn't working is because there's a typo. it says order instead of border!

Comment: Wow, I need some new pair of eyes.  Thank you for the catch!

Comment: That being said it's better practices to do what terra elise said. Remove background-attachment, remove the "scroll right" part in background, and add background-position: right 18px center. 

Alternate to this add background-origin: padding-box and the background will conform to whatever pading you add

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the background-attachment: fixed and change to something like background-position: right 10px center;

Comment: This was attempted but did not change the output.

Comment: @Vahe Did you rewrite? should now be: 
background: url('./resources/icons/icon_warning@2x.png') no-repeat scroll;
background-position: right 10px center;

Comment: That did not affect my output.  I faked it by using a transparent right border and setting width of it.

Comment: Their solution does work if you remove background-attachment:fixed and also remove the "scroll right" from background.

Comment: Cleanest way is to just change the whole background declaration to   background: url('https://s9.postimg.org/h3y0hw3zj/icon_warning_2x.png') no-repeat right 10px center;